# Redirect requests to particular replica in kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, devops, amazon-eks

I am new to Kubernetes.
If there is any service deployed using EKS having 4 replicas A,B,C,D.
Usually loadbalancer directs requests to these replicas
But if I want that my request should go to replica A only or B only...
How can we achieve it.
Request to share some links or steps for guidance

Answer (score 1):

What you could use are the [Headless Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services):

> Sometimes you don't need load-balancing and a single Service IP. In
> this case, you can create what are termed "headless" Services, by
> explicitly specifying `"None"` for the cluster IP (`.spec.clusterIP`).
>
> You can use a headless Service to interface with other service
> discovery mechanisms, without being tied to Kubernetes'
> implementation.
>
> For headless `Services`, a cluster IP is not allocated, kube-proxy
> does not handle these Services, and there is no load balancing or
> proxying done by the platform for them. How DNS is automatically
> configured depends on whether the Service has selectors defined:
>
> - With selectors
>
> For headless Services that define selectors, the endpoints controller
> creates Endpoints records in the API, and modifies the DNS
> configuration to return records (addresses) that point directly to the
> `Pods` backing the `Service`.
>
> - Without selectors
>
> For headless Services that do not define selectors, the endpoints
> controller does not create `Endpoints` records. However, the DNS
> system looks for and configures either:
>
> - CNAME records for [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)-type Services.
> - A records for any `Endpoints` that share a name with the Service, for all other types.

So, a `Headless service` is the same as default `ClusterIP service`, but without  load balancing or proxying and therefore allowing you to connect to a Pod directly.

You can also reference below guides for further assistance:

- [Building a headless service in Kubernetes](https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8)
- [Kubernetes Headless service vs ClusterIP and traffic distribution](https://medium.com/faun/kubernetes-headless-service-vs-clusterip-and-traffic-distribution-904b058f0dfd)